# Reset ctrl + alt + T to operate Evernote Tags instead of Windows 7 tools?

Tags: windows-7, hotkeys, evernote

I use evernote, which uses the hotkey ctrl + alt + t to open a specific window to tag notes.

At some point in time, Windows 7 stole that combination to open a system dialog "Tools for the active window".  It might have been when I installed a second monitor, but I am not sure.

[image]

Can I reset the hotkey to work with Evernote again instead of opening up the "Tools" dialog?

### Update:

with [guenter's](https://superuser.com/users/99960/guenter) help, I figured out that [WinSplit Revolution](http://winsplit-revolution.com/), a window location utility, was overiding the hotkey.  In the options dialog of WinSplit I disabled the combination and regained control of Evernote's window with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have installed a tool that display this dialog, it is not a standard windows dialog, as far as i know. You should try to identify that tool and check if there is the possibility to change the hotkey in that tool.

Comment: Thanks for the direction.  I checked WinSplit Revolution by exiting the process and trying the hotkey with Evernote.  Sure enough, it worked.  WinSplit does allow disable/enabling it's hotkeys through it's options dialog.  done and done.  Thanks for the info.